# Showing only the selected name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the selected text instead of the value because the value is Number. when you select from the option I am using Jquery to pass some data. I am only showing part of the table in which I am facing the issue.

```
<tr>    
<td>Category</td>   
    <td>
<select id="Category" name="size">
    <?php
        dbconnect(); 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT CatID, Name FROM sizeWHERE ppid=:id");
        $stmt->bindParam('id',$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i = 0;
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            if ($i == 0) {
                echo '<option SELECTED value="'.$row['CatID'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
            }else {
                echo '<option value="'.$row['CatID'].'">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
            }
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

**Jquery**
  var cat = $('#Category').text();
   $('#sSize').text(cat);

**Summary**

I want to show the selected option, I tried:

```
var cat = $('#Category').text();
```

but that showed all the options of the `size`.

```
$('#sSize').text(cat);
```

Please how can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the selected option:

```
$('#Category option:selected').val();
```

which gives you the option val.  You can get the text between the option and close tag like:

```
$('#Category option:selected').text();
```

Lastly,  SELECTED doesn't make a select option selected.  You need to do:

```
<option value="whatever" selected="selected">SOME TEXT</option>
```

Comment: "Lastly, SELECTED doesn't make a select option selected" Are you really sure?

Comment: @abhitalks well its browser dependent, where as selected="selected" pretty much always gets the job done.  I guess I can change it to "doesn't necessarily make an option selected"

Comment: @Rooster this is affecting the other select options I have in the form

Comment: @Rooster Actually the "selected" attribute is boolean, and it is required to be just present. The value assigned to it doesn't matter. At least according to the specs: (1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option AND (2) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select AND (3) http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select

Comment: @Rooster Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vY9K3/ Please test it on all browsers you have.

Comment: @abhitalks http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/12/16/option-selectedselected-not-working/  I think this is what I was referring too.  I guess they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the selected value:

```
$('#Category').val();
```

To extract the text of selected option:

```
$('#Category :selected').text();
```

Comment: I am not trying to whos the value because the value is `id` `Int` but the text are words for example 

`<option value "12"> Green </option>`. When the use added to cart I want to show the text not the number because it wouldn't make sense

Comment: the snippet for extracting selected text is also there in the answer

Comment: `selected` is the `id` of a button

Comment: The jQuery selector `'#Category :selected'` will get the currently selected option of the select element called Category.